# plugged in, not charging

Tags: battery, acer-aspire, charging

My acer aspire r7 won't charge and it states "plugged in, not charging."  Looks like this is a fairly common problem people are having.  I have tried many suggested solutions that I I found researching and nothing has worked yet.

There is the "12 step" solution which seems promising:

1. Disconnect AC adapter
2. Shutdown Windows 8
3. Remove battery
4. Connect AC Adapter
5. Power on the laptop
6. Open the Control Panel and select Device Manager
7. Under the Batteries category, right-click all instances of Microsoft ACPI Compliant Control Method Battery , and select Uninstall, even if you have only one (I had two, as shown in figure 1 below)
8. Shutdown
9. Disconnect AC adapter
10. Insert battery
11. Connect AC adapter
12. Power on the laptop

The problem for me with this solution is step 3 which requires you to remove battery and my laptop has an internal battery.  I tried doing all the other steps and no luck.  Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.  Thanks so much, Abbi

Comment: There should be an option in the BIOS to disable internal battery.

Comment: Have you tried starting at step 6?

Comment: At what percentage of battery level does it show this? Mine usually shows it when the battery is fully charged and then stops charging until the battery drops to a certain level then it starts charging again.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that the pin in the charging port could be broken or simply not receiving electricity. Don't be afraid to take a screwdriver to your computer but take precautions.

Comment: An acer aspire r7 charger appears to have a 2-pin charger. If it detects the charger at all then it's most likely not a connection issue.